# Few unknown test cases failing - string operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, time

The following code is not covering all the test cases and **a few cases are failing** while converting a time in -hour AM/PM format, convert it to military (24-hour) time.

**Sample Input:
07:05:45PM**

**Sample Output: 
19:05:45**

All time inputs are valid.

```
 #!/bin/python3

import os
import sys

def timeConversion(s):
    #
    # Write your code here.
    #
    #l = len(s)
    parts = s.split(':')
    print(parts)
    finder = parts[2][2:]
    print(finder)
    parts[2]=int(parts[2][:2])
    print(parts[2])
    tail = str(parts[2])
    print(tail)
    mil = int(parts[0])
#dn = finder(2,:)
    #print(finder)
    if finder == 'PM' and mil<12:
        mil_temp = mil+12
        military = str(mil_temp)
    elif finder == 'AM' and mil<12:
        mil_temp = mil
        military = str(mil_temp)
    elif finder =='AM' and mil==12:
        military = '00'
    elif finder =='PM' and mil==12:
        military = '12'
    fin = military+':'+parts[1]+':'+tail
    return(fin)
```

Comment: What were those test cases inputs?

Comment: @abhiarora Unfortunately I am not aware as HackerRank hid them. So, it's like a mystery to me otherwise I'd have covered them in a conditional check or something.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the built-in `datetime` module as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

input_str = "07:05:45PM"

try:
    output_str = datetime.strptime(input_str, "%I:%M:%S%p").strftime("%H:%M:%S")
except ValueError:
    output_str = None

print(output_str)
```

OUTPUT:

`19:05:45`